# How can I edit a .py file in idle and then save my changes to the original file?

Tags: python

Is it possible to edit a script in idle and then save the changes to the original .py file? Firstly you have to run it using the **exec** command,(*Note: I do not use the idle because I am a linux user and I use the terminal instead.*)then edit it and after all these actions, what can I do to save the changes to the original .py file???

P.S It is obvious I am a beginner so I would appreciate a simple answer(if possible)Thanks :)

Comment: It works similarly to every other editor or IDE, you can just open the .py file ("File" -> "Open..."), modify the code and then press "File" -> "Save" or "Save as...". I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do or if you're doing something wrong. Why do you have to use `exec`?

Comment: @skrx  What I want to do is to edit the file in the terminal. Not just open the file with the text editor and edit it there. What I am asking is for any way to edit my script in the terminal and then save the changes to the original .py file.*Note : not just the terminal, to write code I use the terminal with python3*

Comment: OK, please explain thoroughly what you're trying to do with the files and why you need to edit them.

Comment: And do you actually mean the Linux terminal or the Python shell (the one where you enter Python code with the '>>>' on the left side)?

Comment: @skrx This is my script [1]. Yes, I use the actual linux terminal [2]. What I want to do is to add another *key* and it's *value* to the dictionnary called **epafes**. But the thing is that I want to add it from the terminal (with python3 of course) to the file that is called as you see epafes.py. Even simpler, I want to add a *key* and its *value* to the dictionnary **epafes** using the terminal [3]
[1] = http://imgur.com/a/CFQsu
[2] = http://imgur.com/a/6ABYt
[3] = http://imgur.com/a/tpECd

Comment: You're actually in the Python shell (with the three arrows `>>>`) where you can enter Python code.

Comment: It looks like you're asking the wrong question, so I need to ask more questions first. Do you want to store the `epafes` dictionary (the data that it contains) permanently on your hard disk and keep expanding it in the future? In that case you should store it as a json or maybe a csv file and open it every time the program starts, ask the user for input, add it to the dict and save it again on the hard disk. You could also modify the program, so that you can pass arguments (the new data) to it from the terminal/command-line.

Comment: I can write an example program for you. Do you already have experience with opening, reading and writing text or json files in Python? If not, we probably have to find a tutorial for you first.

Comment: I've just read your previous question and now I think you're actually just looking for a text/code editor or an IDE (Integrated development environment, a software application for software development). Then your question would be off-topic, but you could check out [Thonny](http://thonny.org/) (for beginners), PyCharm (for more experienced users) or text editors like Notepad++ or Sublime Text. You shouldn't try to write your programs in the Python shell.